# How to set height to fit-content but with limitation to 100% of parent height?

Tags: css, height

I need to height of element fit the content but max height cannot be more that 100% of parent height. 
I thought that something like that will make the job:

```
height: min(100%, fit-content);
```

or something like that:

```
height: fit-content;
max-height: 100%;
```

Both attempts don't work and I don't understand why. I will be really grateful for any help!

Comment: [https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#valdef-width-fit-content](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#valdef-width-fit-content)

Comment: Please include your HTML code so we can see it's structure. Let me know when it is included and I'll try to help :)